# Removing Duplicates only when criteria's are met

Tags: sql, duplicates, ssms

Last question in regards to duplication.  I understand how to select duplicate records using COUNT(*) with the HAVING clause > 1, but I'm faced with a challenge of removing duplicates given when a criteria has been met.

I asked one part of this yesterday in removing duplicates when the bill amount cancels out, but now I have to include a criteria to it where when the bill amount has the same positive and negative value that cancels out, the date is the same for both as well as the code.

So for example, record 1 has a bill amount of $250 with code "JUN" and a date of 03/02/2020, record 2 has a bill amount of $250 with code "PII" and a date of 03/07/2020 and record 3 has a bill amount of -$250 with code "PII" and a date of 03/07/2020.  The results I would like to see in this example is only record 1 where record 2 and 3 would be consider the duplicates given the criteria that I stated.

Table Creation:

```
CREATE TABLE Billing (
    BillId varchar(10),
    SerialNo varchar(10),
    BillAmt MONEY,
    Code varchar(5),
    DispenseDt DATE
);
```

Data Entry:

```
INSERT INTO Billing (BillId, SerialNo, BillAmt, Code, DispenseDt)
VALUES ('BL_001','aaa-111',250,'AAP','20200503')
      ,('BL_002','aab-112',250,'ADD','20200309')
      ,('BL_003','aab-112',-250,'ADD','20200309')
      ,('BL_004','aba-120',700,'YED','20200503')
      ,('BL_005','aba-120',370,'TPP','20200822')
      ,('BL_006','aba-120',370,'TPP','20201003')
      ,('BL_007','aba-120',400,'TPP','20200822')
      ,('BL_008','aba-120',-370,'TPP','20200822')
      ,('BL_009','aba-120',-700,'YED','20200503')
      ,('BL_010','baa-201',1000,'TOK','20200927')
      ,('BL_011','baa-201',-1000,'TOK','20200927')
      ,('BL_012','bab-210',1000,'TOK','20200927');
```

Sample Data:

```
+----------+-----------+---------+------+------------+
| BillId  | SerialNo  | BillAmt | Code | DispenseDt |
+----------+-----------+---------+------+------------+
| BL_001   | aaa-111   | $250    | AAP  | 20200503   |
| BL_002   | aab-112   | $250    | ADD  | 20200309   |
| BL_003   | aab-112   |-$250    | ADD  | 20200309   |
| BL_004   | aba-120   | $700    | YED  | 20200503   |
| BL_005   | aba-120   | $370    | TPP  | 20200822   |
| BL_006   | aba-120   | $370    | TPP  | 20201003   |
| BL_007   | aba-120   | $400    | TPP  | 20200822   |
| BL_008   | aba-120   |-$370    | TPP  | 20200822   |
| BL_009   | aba-120   |-$700    | YED  | 20200503   |
| BL_010   | baa-201   | $1000   | TOK  | 20200927   |
| BL_011   | baa-201   |-$1000   | TOK  | 20200927   |
| BL_012   | bab-210   | $1000   | TOK  | 20200927   |
+----------+-----------+---------+------+------------+
```

Desire Results:

```
+----------+-----------+---------+------+------------+
| BillId  | SerialNo  | BillAmt | Code | DispenseDt |
+----------+-----------+---------+------+------------+
| BL_001   | aaa-111   | $250    | AAP  | 20200503   |
| BL_006   | aba-120   | $370    | TPP  | 20201003   |
| BL_007   | aba-120   | $400    | TPP  | 20200822   |
| BL_012   | bab-210   | $1000   | TOK  | 20200927   |
+----------+-----------+---------+------+------------+
```

My Code:

```
select a.SerialNo, a.BillAmt, a.Code, a.DispenseDt
from (
    select *,
      count(SerialNo) over(partition by SerialNo, DispenseDt) b
    from Billing ) a
where b = 1
AND
    InvoiceDt >= '20200601' And InvoiceDt <= '20200630'
    AND
    FacID IN ('IND600','IND605','IND610','IND620','IND630','IND640','IND650','IND660','IND670','IND680','IND690','IND695')
ORDER BY a.Serial;
```

Comment: In your example, would records 2 and 3 be considered duplicate because the balance equals 0?

Comment: @tj cappelletti - yes but also because the date are the same for both as well as the value for code.

Comment: BL_012 shoul not show up since the amount / date and code is same , can you confirm that ?

Answer (score 0):

i tried to solve it but I am kind of stuck myself. The logic here was to get ranks and then filter the rank that is same but somehow my code creates rank [created 2 of them using rank() and row_number()] that will remove some of the cases that you need as output maybe if someone else can edit this code? that would be great

fiddle link:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e0c990d3694ad99b628b3e05a5de624f

```
select 

Bill_ID,
Code,
DispenseDt,
new_bill_amt,
rank()
over(partition by new_bill_amt,DispenseDt, code) as rank_,
row_number()
over(partition by new_bill_amt,DispenseDt, code) as rank_2

from (
select
*,
replace(billamt,'-','') as new_bill_amt
from Billing
) as f
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work.

(I used a CTE, but you could convert that into a subquery.)

```
WITH base_cte AS (
    SELECT 
        B1.SerialNo
    ,   SUM(B1.BillAmt) AS [TotAmt]
    ,   B1.Code
    ,   B1.DispenseDt
    FROM #Billing AS B1
    GROUP BY 
        B1.SerialNo
    ,   B1.Code
    ,   B1.DispenseDt
)
SELECT 
    B.BillId
,   B.SerialNo
,   B.BillAmt
,   B.code
,   B.DispenseDt
FROM #Billing AS B
LEFT JOIN base_cte AS X ON X.SerialNo = B.SerialNo
WHERE X.TotAmt = B.BillAmt 
AND X.DispenseDt = B.DispenseDt
```

Output:

```
BillId  SerialNo  BillAmt   code    DispenseDt
BL_001  aaa-111   250.00    AAP     2020-05-03
BL_006  aba-120   370.00    TPP     2020-10-03
BL_007  aba-120   400.00    TPP     2020-08-22
BL_012  bab-210   1000.00   TOK     2020-09-27
```

EDIT: Here's a different method with OVER().

```
SELECT 
    Y.BillId
,   Y.SerialNo
,   Y.BillAmt
,   Y.Code
,   Y.DispenseDt
FROM (
    SELECT X.*
    ,   [Ct] = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY X.code, X.TotAmt, X.DispenseDt ORDER BY X.SerialNo, X.code, X.DispenseDt)
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            B.BillId
        ,   B.SerialNo
        ,   B.BillAmt
        ,   B.code
        ,   B.DispenseDt
        ,   [TotAmt] = SUM(B.BillAmt) OVER(PARTITION BY B.SerialNo, B.code, B.DispenseDt ORDER BY B.SerialNo, B.code, B.DispenseDt)
        FROM #Billing AS B
    ) AS X
) AS Y
WHERE Y.BillAmt = Y.TotAmt
ORDER BY Y.BillId
```